# Issue with Redirecting stdout to Tkinter text widget with threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter, stdout

My program which prints an infinite set of numbers works as expected only if you print something after redirecting `sys.stdout` otherwise the program freezes, Why is this? Is this a bug?

code:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import sys
import threading

def func():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i +=1
        print i

class Std_redirector(object):
    def __init__(self,widget):
        self.widget = widget

    def write(self,string):
        self.widget.see(Tk.END)
        self.widget.insert("end",string)


root = Tk.Tk()
text = Tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

sys.stdout = Std_redirector(text) #Redirect stdout to Tkinter text widget

#print 'hey' #If you uncomment this line, the program works!

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=func)
thread1.start() #Starts printing

root.mainloop()
```

This script works if you have this line uncommented : `print 'hey'`

By the way my OS is windows 7

Comment: It works for me - directly in Python. In `DreamPie` python shell similar to `IDLE` I got error `'Std_redirector' object has no attribute 'flush'` but it still works. (Linux Mint, Python 2.7.5)

Comment: @furas over here at python 2.7 in windows 7 it doesn't...

Comment: @furas oh did you actually comment the `print 'hey'` line... BTW just run the updated code

Comment: http://www.effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm

Comment: @K DawG new version (as old one) works with and without `print 'hey'` but I use Linux. It can be only Windows issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tinkered around the idea and found two ways to make it work.

1) Your approach works even if it is not thread safe. Only problem seems to be that the application needs to be initialized before printing to the widget starts. If you would like to start the second thread "immediately" and not from some callback, this works for me:

```
root.after(100, thread1.start)
```

2) Second and more clean approach is based at example linked by @falsetru . However it requires you to print to stdout by reasonable speed so updates would not choke on it.

```
from Tkinter import *
import threading
import Queue # This is thread safe
import time

class Std_redirector():
    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget

    def write(self,string):
        self.widget.write(string)

class ThreadSafeText(Text):
    def __init__(self, master, **options):
        Text.__init__(self, master, **options)
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.update_me()

    def write(self, line):
        self.queue.put(line)

    def update_me(self):
        while not self.queue.empty():
            line = self.queue.get_nowait()
            self.insert(END, line)
            self.see(END)
            self.update_idletasks()
        self.after(10, self.update_me)

def func():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        print i
        time.sleep(0.01)

root = Tk()
text = ThreadSafeText(root)
text.pack()
sys.stdout = Std_redirector(text)

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=func)
thread1.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Based on my experience from other GUI toolkits I wanted to use `root.after_idle()` but it did not work as I have expected it to.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful, BTW is this a bug?

Comment: I do not know. Just starting with Tk. But experience with other GUI libraries has always been that you are not supposed to update your GUI outside the main GUI thread anyway. It is usual to use events to propagate the call to main GUI thread, but that did not work for me in Tkinter either.